# Trouble with Transmission

Tags: permissions, 15.10, transmission

I have a 30gb root setup, and when i download anything from `Transmission`, it takes up the whole 30 gb. The save to location is `Downloads`. I tried changing the location to `/media/.../Downloads`, which has >200gb size, but it says I don't have permission, which i know I don't btw. How can I give **only** `Transmission` the permission to make this change. I am using it on another user profile, and therefore the permission issues.

It's an Ubuntu 15.10 machine.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Run transmission with *sudo* privileges by.

Opening a new terminal by pressing

```
Ctrl + Alt + T
```

In that new window type

```
sudo transmission
```

Press enter

It will ask for your password type that in and press enter

Now transmission will be running with elevated privileges so it can access the downloads folder.

Hope this helps, if it did mark this post as answered

Zimbinskers